# STM32 HAL I2C DMA + Si4703 FM tuner

Tags: stm32

[image: Si4703 2-wire mode timing diagram]

[image: Si4703 2-wire mode description 1]

[image: Si4703 2-wire mode description 2]

Ни как не пойму как в режиме DMA можно общаться по I2C с Si4703.
В HAL имеются следующие функции:

*I don’t understand how in I2C DMA mode it is possible to communicate with Si4703. HAL has the following functions:*

```
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA, HAL_I2C_Master_Receive_DMA, HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_DMA, HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_DMA
```

Но как они передают адрес устройства по I2C? В коде я не нашел ничего по поводу передачи `DevAddress`. С помощью какой комбинации функций я могу отправить адрес, а затем ожидать данные? Интересует именно DMA режим.

*But how do they transmit the device address via I2C? In the code, I did not find anything about the transfer of `DevAddress`. What combination of functions can I use to send a device address and then wait for data? Interested in DMA mode.*

Answer (score 0):

В функции `HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit_DMA(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size)` параметр DevAddress используется для задания адреса FM тюнера.
Этот адрес запоминается в структуре для дальнейшего использования поля этой структуры для копирования адреса Slave в один из контрол регистров микроконтроллера. В HAL драйвере это делается в прерывании. Поэтому, обязательно не забудьте, что при использовании DMA прерывания тоже должны быть разрешены и определены. После установки Start бита на шине генерируется старт последовательность и далее приходит event, что наступила фаза установки адреса.  Вызывается прерывание и в нем устанавливается адрес slave устройства.

```
/* ADDR Set --------------------------------------------------------------*/
else if ((I2C_CHECK_FLAG(sr1itflags, I2C_FLAG_ADDR) != RESET) && (I2C_CHECK_IT_SOURCE(itsources, I2C_IT_EVT) != RESET))
{
  I2C_Master_ADDR(hi2c);
}
```

---

@МихаилСинельников, подскажите, какое семейство STM32 вы используете?